# MSSQL to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, database-migration

I'm having difficulty converting this line of MSSQL:

```
Union All 
Select 1,table_name,3,4,5,6,7,8 
from (select top 1 table_name 
      from information_schema.tables 
      order by 1) as subname 
order by 1 desc
```

to Oracle.

So far I have:

```
Union All 
Select 1,table_name,3,4,5,6,7,8 
from 
   (select * 
    from 
      (select table_name 
       from all_tables order by 1) 
    where rownum <= 1) as subname 
order by 1 desc
```

The error that's thrown is

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

Solution found, see first comment.

Solution:

```
Union All Select 1,table_name,3,4,5,6,7,8 from (select * from (select table_name from all_tables order by 1) where rownum <= 1) subname order by 1 desc--
```

Comment: try removing 'as' before subname

Comment: Oh thanks! That worked!

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 1,table_name,3,4,5,6,7,8 
    FROM (
       SELECT * 
       FROM (
          SELECT table_name 
          FROM all_tables 
          ORDER BY 1) 
       WHERE rownum <= 1) subname 
    ORDER BY 1 desc;
```

In order to name the subquery in Oracle, you do not use the `as` keyword. Just place the name directly after the parentheses.

Comment: Is this true of Oracle versions? This is very interesting!

Comment: I believe it uses AS if you use a With statement instead of a nested query